# Differentiate pages in angular without the app.component.html template

Tags: angular

In Angular, the app.component.html is like a template to other pages. Sign in sign up pages are totally different from project pages.They don't even use header footer. So how can I build them without app.component.html tags.

Comment: Move all your common parts (header/footer) in a layour component, add a router-outlet in app.component, and in your routing files specify Layout and login page as entry points

Comment: I could not understand what you said. Can you bit explain or provide me an example